# Problem manipulating text using grep

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

I want to search for a line that contains `log4j` and take 7 lines before and 3 lines after the match.

> grep -B7 -A3 "log4j" web.xml

After that I want to add comment tags before this paragraph and after it.

```
<!--
paragraph that i found by grep
-->
```

I wrote this script bellow:

```
search=`find . -name 'web.xml'`
text=`grep -B7 -A3 "log4j" $search`
sed -i "/$text/c $newparagraph" $search
```

It's not working. Is there any way to just add comment symbol not replace the paragraph?

What I want to the script to do:

1. search for the paragraph
2. append

   append --> at the end

**Edit**: This is the paragraph that am trying manipulate :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listenerclass>
        org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

This paragraph is part of many paragraphs! I want make it like this:

```
<!--
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listenerclass>
        org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
-->
```

Comment: It's likely your script didn't work because 'log4j' occurs twice in the section of interest. I've tested my solution and it works for the example provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be better done with an XML library, but here it is in sed...

Sed has `i` and `a` commands for inserting and appending lines. I think the following script will help.

```
sed -n '/log4jConfigLocation/=' < test.test |\
while read index; do
    sed -i $search -e "$((index-1)) i\ <\!--" -e "$((index+8)) a\ -->" < $search
done
```

The first part, `sed -n '/log4jConfigLocation/=' will get the line numbers that have 'log4jConfigLocation'. The next part uses those line numbers in two commands: insert a line 1 line above, and append a line 8 lines below.

There is a better way using sed's hold buffer, but I'm not familiar enough with it; if you're interested, you can see [this guide](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-39). Ultimately, though, if you're going to be working with this type of stuff regularly, you should check out [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks 4 replay ,, i have changed the procedure because sometimes XML file would be changed i mean it could be not always 8 line to the up or 3 line to the bottom....

Comment: @moata_u I expected that to be a problem, which is why XMLStarlet would be good to look at. It's an XML tool that makes parsing this stuff much more robust.